# After save RuntimeError: Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

React app is making calls to ruby on rails api. I'm building signup page i got stuck on the signup save part. getting error

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "#<RuntimeError: Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id: 7, email: \"bearatamer+testfive@gmail.com\", created_at: \"2019-06-19 05:35:58\", updated_at: \"2019-06-19 05:35:58\", fullname: \"test five\", provider: nil, uid: nil, image: nil, phone_number: \"6021233423\", description: nil, pin: nil, phone_verified: nil, stripe_id: nil, merchant_id: nil, unread: 0, access_token: \"JHqM4JiyjvdufcReQdYX\", is_commercial_host: false>>"
```

im sending this JSON

```
{"fullname": "test five", "phone_number": "6021233423",  "email": 
 "testuser+testfive@gmail.com",
"is_commercial_host": "false",  "password": "test1234"
}
```

to this api

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/v1/signup
```

as you see on the below image 
[image]

this image is from the command line 
[image]

**The record gets saved to the database but after it saves i get the error**

[image]

this is users_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:logout]

def facebook
 enter code hereif params[:facebook_access_token]
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:facebook_access_token])
  user_data = graph.get_object("me?fields=name,email,id,picture")

  user = User.find_by(email: user_data['email'])
  if user
    user.generate_authentication_token
    user.save
    render json: user, status: :ok
  else
    user = User.new(
                fullname: user_data['fullname'],
                email: user_data['email'],
                uid: user_data['id'],
                provider: 'Facebook',
                image: user_data['picture']['data']['url']
            )
    user.generate_authentication_token

    if user.save
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: user.errors, is_success: false}, status: 422
    end
  end
  else
  render json: { error: "Invalid Facebook Token", is_success: false}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def logout
 user = User.find_by(access_token: params[:access_token])
 user.generate_authentication_token
 user.save
 render json: { is_success: true}, status: :ok
end

def login
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     render json: user, status: :ok
    else
     render json: { error: user.errors, is_success: false}, status: 422
    end 
end

def signup
 user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
 if user 
   render json: { error: "Email already exist, click on forget password", is_success: false}, status: :unprocessable_entity
 else
    user = User.new(
                fullname: params[:fullname],
                email: params[:email],
                phone_number: params[:phone_number],
                password:  params[:password],
                is_commercial_host:  params[:is_commercial_host]
            )
    user.generate_authentication_token
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { success: "Email already exist, click on forget password", is_success: true}, status: :ok
    end
  end 
 end

end
```

here is routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
namespace :api, defautls: {format: :json} do
namespace :v1 do
  get '/logout' => 'users#logout'
  get '/login' => 'users#login'
  post '/login' => 'users#login'
  post '/signup' => 'users#signup'
  end
 end
end
```

here is user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_secure_password
 before_create :generate_authentication_token
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
 :validatable,
     :confirmable, :omniauthable
 validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 
 50}
end
def generate_authentication_token
 begin
  self.access_token = Devise.friendly_token
 end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
end
```

The Error happens on line 64 of signup method on the users_controller.rb which is this line

```
 if user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

this fixed the error

```
   devise_for :admins, :class_name => 'User'
```